# Can't display api(downloaded) image on APK React native Expo

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, expo, apk

I'm using 44 Sdk version(last) 0.64.3 RN

At first, in dev mode(run locally) everything fine.

But in APK(expo build:android) I have one problem. There are two images that works fine

1. random image from network
2. static image from assets

```
    <Image  style={{width: 400, height: 400}}
            resizeMode='contain' source={{uri:'https://kakpishem.ru/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/pravopisanie_suffiksov_ova_eva_yva_iva_v_glagolah_main.jpg'}}
    />
 
    <Image  style={{width: 400, height: 400}}
            resizeMode='contain' source={require('./assets/en.png')}
    />
```

But my goal is display this image:

```
<Image  style={{width: 400, height: 400}}
            resizeMode='contain'
            source={{uri:'https://agis.kz:5115/api/file/download?fileId=5fb2268d99ff0a0012a615a5'}}
    />
```

If you follow the link, it downloads image. I think app cannot download image on time and display it. I also tried to use some properties such as onLoad, onLoadStart, etc. (from docs)